# Java - Storing userinput using Arrays and Methods

Tags: java

I am trying to ask the user to enter 10 names using arrays, and then return the method. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class methodbankinput
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {

       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
       String[] names = {};

          printarray(names);
  } 


public static void printarray(String[] names) 
{   


    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter 10 names" + i);
    names = kb.nextLine();
    }
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code won't compile. You've defined Scanner kb in your main and you can't see it inside printarray.

You've also declared a 0-length array. I don't think that's what you want.

And to store something in an array, you need to specify what index you want to store the value in. Arrays are also zero-indexed so i should start at 0, as so.

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) // You could use i < 10 as well
{
    System.out.println("Please enter 10 names" + i);
    names[i] = kb.nextLine();
}
```